# I am not able to put index as ${i} inside reportValues array. There are some jstl syntax exception at line no 3

Tags: jsp

I am not able to put index as ${i} inside reportValues array. There are some jstl syntax exception at line no 3

```
      <c:forEach items="${reportPreview}" var="reportValues">
      <c:forEach var="i" begin="11" end="20">
      <td>${reportValues[${i}]}</td>      //Line no 3
      </c:forEach>
      </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please post the exception messages in your question.

Comment: @rakesh Please review the answer given below and let us know if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<c:forEach items="${reportPreview}" varStatus="loop">
    <td>${reportPreview[loop.index]}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

You can use the `varStatus` loop variable to get the index of the current loop evaluation.